# How to use regex in Spark Scala to convert RDD to Dataframe after reading an unstructured text file?

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark

```
    package sparkscala2.test
    
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
    import org.apache.spark.sql
    import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.regexp_extract
    
    
    object example1 {
      //case class MyType(Field_Name: String)
     // case class click(rowtime:Map[String,String])
      case class click(rowtime:String,key:String,ip:String,userid:String,remote_user:String,time:String,_time:String,request:String,status:String,bytes:String,referrer:String,agent:String)
      def main(args:Array[String]):Unit={
       System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\hadoop\\")
       val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("test").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
        spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("Error")
          import spark.implicits._
       val rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile("file:///C://Users//User//Desktop//test1.txt")
        val clean_rdd=rdd.map(x=>x.replace("value: {","")).map(x=>x.replace("}","")).map(x=>x.replace("\"",""))
        
        
          val schema_rdd=clean_rdd.map(x=>x.split(",")).map(x=>click(x(0).split(":")(1),x(1).split(":")(1),x(2).split(":")(1),x(3).split(":")(1),x(4).split(":")(1),x(5).split(":")(1),
         x(6).split(":")(1),x(7).split(":")(1),x(8).split(":")(1),x(9).split(":")(1),x(10).split(":")(1),x(11).split(":")(1)))
     val final_df=schema_rdd.toDF()
     final_df.show(false)
      }
    }
    
input file : test1.txt

rowtime: 2020/06/11 10:38:42.449 Z, key: 222.90.225.227, value: {"ip":"222.90.225.227","userid":12,"remote_user":"-","time":"1","_time":1,"request":"GET /images/logo-small.png HTTP/1.1","status":"302","bytes":"1289","referrer":"-","agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"}
rowtime: 2020/06/11 10:38:42.528 Z, key: 111.245.174.248, value: {"ip":"111.245.174.248","userid":30,"remote_user":"-","time":"11","_time":11,"request":"GET /site/login.html HTTP/1.1","status":"302","bytes":"14096","referrer":"-","agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"}
rowtime: 2020/06/11 10:38:42.705 Z, key: 122.152.45.245, value: {"ip":"122.152.45.245","userid":11,"remote_user":"-","time":"21","_time":21,"request":"GET /images/logo-small.png HTTP/1.1","status":"407","bytes":"4196","referrer":"-","agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"}

       
output:

+--------------+----------------+---------------+------+-----------+----+-----+-----------------------------------+------+-----+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|rowtime       |key             |ip             |userid|remote_user|time|_time|request                            |status|bytes|referrer|agent                                                              |
+--------------+----------------+---------------+------+-----------+----+-----+-----------------------------------+------+-----+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2020/06/11 10| 222.90.225.227 |222.90.225.227 |12    |-          |1   |1    |GET /images/logo-small.png HTTP/1.1|302   |1289 |-       |Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML|
| 2020/06/11 10| 111.245.174.248|111.245.174.248|30    |-          |11  |11   |GET /site/login.html HTTP/1.1      |302   |14096|-       |Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML|
| 2020/06/11 10| 122.152.45.245 |122.152.45.245 |11    |-          |21  |21   |GET /images/logo-small.png HTTP/1.1|407   |4196 |-       |Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML|
+--------------+----------------+---------------+------+-----------+----+-----+-----------------------------------+------+-----+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have tried the above code, but in the output, the rowtime and agent column data are not completely displayed due to semicolon and comma in the data. rowtime column has semicolon in the data and so the remaining data didn't got displayed, since I have done split with semicolon to separate the key/value and for agent column we have comma in the data and the so the remaining data didn't get displayed, because in the beginning as I have used split with comma.

Is there any way that I can use the regex function while mapping with the case class schema? Or any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using case classes and RDD you can read file as dataset/dataframe then do transformation to get the desired result.

```
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
  spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
  import spark.implicits._

  // Assuming you have fixed structure. You can improvise this regex as required
  val regex = "([a-z-A-Z]+:\\s+)([\\s+\\d:\\./]+Z)([,\\s+a-z-A-Z]+:\\s+)([\\d\\.]+)([,\\s+]+[a-z-A-Z]+:)(.*)"
  /*
  ([a-z-A-Z]+:\\s+) --> Matches rowtime:
  ([\\s+\\d:\\./]+Z)  --> Matches rowtime value eg. 2020/06/11 10:38:42.449 Z
  ([,\\s+a-z-A-Z]+:\\s+) --> Matches , key:
  ([\\d\\.]+)  --> Matches content of key e.g 222.90.225.227
  ([,\\s+]+[a-z-A-Z]+:)  --> Matches , value:
  (.*) --> Matches content of value field which is in json
   */

  // Read file as dataframe and using regex and grouping ID extract column content
  var df = spark.read.textFile("sample.txt")
    .select(regexp_extract('value, regex, 2).as("rowtime"),
      regexp_extract('value, regex, 4).as("key"),
      regexp_extract('value, regex, 6).as("value"))

  // Since value is json we can make use from_json to create struct field
  df = df.withColumn("value", from_json('value, schema_of_json(df.select("value").first().getString(0))))

  // select all the column including nested columns of value column
  df.select("rowtime", "key", "value.*").show(false)
+-------------------------+---------------+-----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+---------------+--------+-----------+-----------------------------------+------+----+------+
|rowtime                  |key            |_time|agent                                                                                                              |bytes|ip             |referrer|remote_user|request                            |status|time|userid|
+-------------------------+---------------+-----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+---------------+--------+-----------+-----------------------------------+------+----+------+
|2020/06/11 10:38:42.449 Z|222.90.225.227 |1    |Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36|1289 |222.90.225.227 |-       |-          |GET /images/logo-small.png HTTP/1.1|302   |1   |12    |
|2020/06/11 10:38:42.528 Z|111.245.174.248|11   |Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36|14096|111.245.174.248|-       |-          |GET /site/login.html HTTP/1.1      |302   |11  |30    |
|2020/06/11 10:38:42.705 Z|122.152.45.245 |21   |Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36|4196 |122.152.45.245 |-       |-          |GET /images/logo-small.png HTTP/1.1|407   |21  |11    |
+-------------------------+---------------+-----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+---------------+--------+-----------+-----------------------------------+------+----+------+
```

Comment: Thank you Mohana for the regex expression...  am not much expert in the regex.. need to learn. would you please recommend any good link to refer these regex expressions.

Comment: Even I also need to learn a lot w.r.t regex. You can refer this link for quick reference->https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285.  I would recommend this online regex editor for practice-->https://regex101.com/.

Comment: You can read about all the function I used here-->https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html.

Comment: thank you. what is that "SCHEMA_OF_JSON" in the code? Is that any struct field that you wrote? if so can you please paste it here. or do i need to import anything for this.?

Comment: schema_of_json is a built-in function which will extract schema from a JSON string, it's available from spark V2.4.0.

Comment: ok got it...what is the import for SCHEMA_OF_JSON? Actually am using spark 2.3.1... so its showing error for me when am trying in my local

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236287/discussion-between-anonymous-and-mohana-b-c).

Answer (score 1):

Your data almost looks like JSON but missing some double-quotes for few fields and the final flower bracket wrapper.

Try the below - more of spark-sql approach

Mimic the dataframe using hardcoded string. You can get this from file.

```
val df = Seq("""rowtime: 2020/06/11 10:38:42.528 Z, key: 111.245.174.248, value: {"ip":"111.245.174.248","userid":30,"remote_user":"-","time":"11","_time":11,"request":"GET /site/login.html HTTP/1.1","status":"302","bytes":"14096","referrer":"-","agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"} """,
            """rowtime: 2020/06/11 10:38:42.528 Z, key: 111.245.174.248, value: {"ip":"111.245.174.248","userid":30,"remote_user":"-","time":"11","_time":11,"request":"GET /site/login.html HTTP/1.1","status":"302","bytes":"14096","referrer":"-","agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"}""",
            """rowtime: 2020/06/11 10:38:42.705 Z, key: 122.152.45.245, value: {"ip":"122.152.45.245","userid":11,"remote_user":"-","time":"21","_time":21,"request":"GET /images/logo-small.png HTTP/1.1","status":"407","bytes":"4196","referrer":"-","agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"}""" 
            ).toDF("x")
```

Create a temp view

```
df.show(false)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
```

Input data:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|x                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|rowtime: 2020/06/11 10:38:42.528 Z, key: 111.245.174.248, value: {"ip":"111.245.174.248","userid":30,"remote_user":"-","time":"11","_time":11,"request":"GET /site/login.html HTTP/1.1","status":"302","bytes":"14096","referrer":"-","agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"}   |
|rowtime: 2020/06/11 10:38:42.528 Z, key: 111.245.174.248, value: {"ip":"111.245.174.248","userid":30,"remote_user":"-","time":"11","_time":11,"request":"GET /site/login.html HTTP/1.1","status":"302","bytes":"14096","referrer":"-","agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"}   |
|rowtime: 2020/06/11 10:38:42.705 Z, key: 122.152.45.245, value: {"ip":"122.152.45.245","userid":11,"remote_user":"-","time":"21","_time":21,"request":"GET /images/logo-small.png HTTP/1.1","status":"407","bytes":"4196","referrer":"-","agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"}|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now transform the single-column "x" using the regex functions to fix the double-quotes issues plus the flower brackets to make it a valid json literal

```
val df1 = spark.sql("""
with t1 ( select x from df ),
     t2 ( select regexp_replace(x,"(rowtime|key|value):","\"$1\":") x from t1 ),
     t3 ( select regexp_replace(x,"(\"rowtime\":)\\s+([^,]+),","$1 \"$2\",") x from t2 ),
     t4 ( select regexp_replace(x,"(\"key\":)\\s+([^,]+),","$1 \"$2\",") x from t3 )
     select '{'||x||'}' y from t4  
""")
df1.printSchema()
```

Now each row of column "y" is a valid json literal.
Convert this dataframe with single column that has json string with below dataframe step

```
import spark.implicits._ 
val df2 = spark.read.json(df1.as[String])

df2.printSchema

root
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- rowtime: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _time: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- agent: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- bytes: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ip: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- referrer: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- remote_user: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- request: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- status: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- time: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- userid: long (nullable = true)
```

Create a view on top of this

```
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("df2")
```

Now, use the spark-sql and get the needed elements for the output.

```
spark.sql("""
select rowtime , key, value.ip ip, value.userid userid, value.remote_user remote_user, 
value.time time, value._time _time, value.request request, value.status status, value.bytes bytes, 
value.referrer referrer, value.agent agent
from df2
""").show(false)
```

Output:

```
+-------------------------+---------------+---------------+------+-----------+----+-----+-----------------------------------+------+-----+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|rowtime                  |key            |ip             |userid|remote_user|time|_time|request                            |status|bytes|referrer|agent                                                                                                              |
+-------------------------+---------------+---------------+------+-----------+----+-----+-----------------------------------+------+-----+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|2020/06/11 10:38:42.528 Z|111.245.174.248|111.245.174.248|30    |-          |11  |11   |GET /site/login.html HTTP/1.1      |302   |14096|-       |Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36|
|2020/06/11 10:38:42.528 Z|111.245.174.248|111.245.174.248|30    |-          |11  |11   |GET /site/login.html HTTP/1.1      |302   |14096|-       |Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36|
|2020/06/11 10:38:42.705 Z|122.152.45.245 |122.152.45.245 |11    |-          |21  |21   |GET /images/logo-small.png HTTP/1.1|407   |4196 |-       |Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36|
+-------------------------+---------------+---------------+------+-----------+----+-----+-----------------------------------+------+-----+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```